# Do I need a new UK visa if I changed jobs in the US and my previous visa was from the employer?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I live in the US. I am an Indian citizen. I have a valid UK business visa from my previous employer.

I want to travel to the UK in the next 3 months. Do I need to get a new visa, or my previous Visa is valid.

Comment: That's a great way to get a 10 year ban. The expiry date on your visa may be in the future, but it's absolutely not valid if it's from your previous employer.  And they WILL ban if you get caught trying abuse like that.

Comment: Since when do employers issue visas?

Comment: @Henning. As you know, some types of visa are specific to an employer. e.g. [Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) - I guess when the OP says "*from* my previous employer" they probably mean their previous employer handled most of the application process for them.

Comment: Exactly what visa do you have, and why do you say it came from your previous employer?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's a shorthand way of saying "the Tier 2 visa sponsored by the employer that issued my certificate who is now my previous employer".